# “open” command becomes “eject” in Windows 10 DVD drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, dvd

I see a strange problem in my Windows 10 Laptop.

When I right-clink the DVD drive and then click "open" in the pop-up menu, it ejects the DVD disk.

This happens to my external DVD drive and also internal DVD drive. What is wrong here? How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Is there a disk in the drive? if it is empty that what happens..

Comment: It has a disk inside. I guess what happened is if the driver cannot read the DVD, it will behave like this.